# Liquibase: ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am trying to create a db on PostgreSQL using liquibase. This is my dbchangelog file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
  <changeSet  author="testuser"  id="3">
    <sql  dbms="postgresql"
            endDelimiter=";">
            CREATE DATABASE testdb;
    </sql>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog
```

When i try to run `liquibase update` from my project directory i am getting

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE DATABASE testdb]
```

I saw setting  AUTOCOMMIT = ON in PostgreSQL  will solve this issue.But this method only works for PostgreSQL 9.4 and below . But i am using AWS RDS PostgreSQL 9.6.8

Comment: you shouldn't be creating your tables as a superuser to  begin with

Answer (score 11):

Short:
add `runInTransaction="false"` to your `changeSet`.

Explanation:

Liquibase opens a transaction block in order to guarantee that a `changeSet`s are executed fully or not at all.

PostgreSQL doc says: `CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.` ( see [PostgreSQL Doc on Create Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createdatabase.html)!)

So there is clearly a conflicting behavior, which can only be avoided, by not using a transaction block.

Be advised that deactivation the transaction behavior with multiple commands, can lead to the problem that a changeSet is only partly executed.

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: I've tried this; using native sql migration format. This is my changeset line: `--changeset njohnson:create-db-0 runInTransaction="false"`; followed by of course `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;`. Doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @NateJ
little bit late, but have you tried `--changeset njohnson:create-db-0 runInTransaction:false`?

native sql as well as the yaml format use `:` instead of `=`. also i think the `"` are not required in both.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase is not intended for database creation. You should have your db schema prepared and liquibase will populate it with your tables/indexes/...